# Adding AdBlock to Layout Android

Tags: android, admob, markup

I'm new at android developing, so asking you for help.

I have the code like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/home_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/adView">
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar" />
</LinearLayout>

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</LinearLayout>
```

In my logic, AdBlock should display at the bottom of view. But in my case it's just not appearing at all. If I past Ad's markup inside `LinearLayout` it gives me crash of VM.

What I'm doing wrong? Thank you in advance

UPD: Java activity

```
public class PddViewActivity extends ActionBarActivity{

private WebView webView;
private ProgressBar progressBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pdd_view);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    String file = getIntent().getStringExtra("file");

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);


    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
            Log.i("PROGRESS IS :", newProgress+"");
            progressBar.setProgress(newProgress);
        }
    });

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: " + description + " " + failingUrl, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            if (progressBar.getVisibility() == WebView.VISIBLE) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(WebView.GONE);
            }
        }
    });

    webView.loadUrl(String.format("file:///android_asset/html/%s", file));

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Comment: Have you any error when you try to compile ? What is the Java code corresponding to your activity ?

Comment: Retry and follow those instructions : [AdMob QuickStart](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start)

Comment: @CyprienAubry updated with the activity code. I can display ad on others views, so no problem with that. Compiling shows no errors :)

Comment: Okay, I see now, you did not instanciated the AdView. Retry by following all the instructions at the link I give in the previous comment ;)

Comment: @CyprienAubry okay, i will try that. but in other views I havent instanced AdView, and Ads displayed well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `home_layout` has a `layoutHeight` of `match_parent`, which means it will consume all the height of its parent leaving none for you adView.

Instead use `wrap_content` and specify `android:layoutWeight="1"` to tell it to consume all unused space. Eg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/home_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar" />
</LinearLayout>

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Note also:

1. `layout_above` has no meaning except within a relative_layout.
2. `fill_parent` has been deprecated, use `match_parent` instead.
3. You had the same problem with your WebView.

Answer (score 1):

Try with that in your PddViewActivity.java :

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

private WebView webView;
private ProgressBar progressBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pdd_view);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    //instaciate AdView
    AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

String file = getIntent().getStringExtra("file");

webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);


webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
        Log.i("PROGRESS IS :", newProgress+"");
        progressBar.setProgress(newProgress);
    }
});

webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: " + description + " " + failingUrl, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        if (progressBar.getVisibility() == WebView.VISIBLE) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(WebView.GONE);
        }
    }
});

webView.loadUrl(String.format("file:///android_asset/html/%s", file));

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
}
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: hehe, instactiated as You did, but same thing :( no adds on there.

Comment: Do you add the dependencies in the Gradle config file ?

Comment: yeap, im using ver. 7.5 : compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.5.0'